# Python ez_install : UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xae in position 11

Tags: python, setuptools

Getting the error below trying to install ez_install, Windows 7 64 bit machine with fresh Python 2.7.  Any ideas?

```
Installing Setuptools
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 17, in 
    exec(init_file.read(), command_ns)
  File "", line 8, in 
  File "c:\users\namar\appdata\local\temp\tmp1tanvy\setuptools-2.1\setuptools\__
init__.py", line 11, in 
    from setuptools.extension import Extension
  File "c:\users\namar\appdata\local\temp\tmp1tanvy\setuptools-2.1\setuptools\ex
tension.py", line 5, in 
    from setuptools.dist import _get_unpatched
  File "c:\users\namar\appdata\local\temp\tmp1tanvy\setuptools-2.1\setuptools\di
st.py", line 15, in 
    from setuptools.compat import numeric_types, basestring
  File "c:\users\namar\appdata\local\temp\tmp1tanvy\setuptools-2.1\setuptools\co
mpat.py", line 19, in 
    from SimpleHTTPServer import SimpleHTTPRequestHandler
  File "c:\python27\lib\SimpleHTTPServer.py", line 27, in 
    class SimpleHTTPRequestHandler(BaseHTTPServer.BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
  File "c:\python27\lib\SimpleHTTPServer.py", line 208, in SimpleHTTPRequestHand
ler
    mimetypes.init() # try to read system mime.types
  File "c:\python27\lib\mimetypes.py", line 358, in init
    db.read_windows_registry()
  File "c:\python27\lib\mimetypes.py", line 258, in read_windows_registry
    for subkeyname in enum_types(hkcr):
  File "c:\python27\lib\mimetypes.py", line 249, in enum_types
    ctype = ctype.encode(default_encoding) # omit in 3.x!
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xae in position 11: ordinal
 not in range(128)
Something went wrong during the installation.
See the error message above.


C:\Users\namar\Downloads>cd\

C:\>cd Python27
```

Answer (score 1):

I met the same problem, solved it by deleting non-ASCII character in window registry "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\MIME\Database\Content Type" and it works.The reason is

```
 ctype = ctype.encode(default_encoding)
```

will throw UnicodeDecodeError when it met non-ASCII characters and the program will stop.

Answer (score 1):

Check this link.(http://blog.csdn.net/hugleecool/article/details/17996993).

In C:\Python27\Lib\mimetypes.py find next string

```
default_encoding = sys.getdefaultencoding()
```

replace it with

```
if sys.getdefaultencoding() != 'gbk':  
    reload(sys)  
    sys.setdefaultencoding('gbk')  
default_encoding = sys.getdefaultencoding()
```

Notice: instead 'gbk' choose your encoding.

Answer (score 0):

In `C:\Python27\Lib\mimetypes.py` find next string

default_encoding = sys.getdefaultencoding()

replace it with

```
if sys.getdefaultencoding() != 'gbk':  
    reload(sys)  
    sys.setdefaultencoding('gbk')  
default_encoding = sys.getdefaultencoding()
```

**Notice:** instead 'gbk' choose your encoding.

The above answer satisfies my case of unicode decode error in using google app engine local web server for php and python .

Answer (score 0):

In my case, simply comment the following four line worked,

```
try:
    ctype = ctype.encode(default_encoding) # omit in 3.x!
except UnicodeEncodeError:
    pass
```

And replace `UnicodeEncodeError` to be `UnicodeError` worked.

For more info, you can check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4237898/unicodedecodeerror-ascii-codec-cant-decode-byte-0xe0-in-position-0-ordinal) question.