# Cannot install pylint on Windows 7 x64, Python 2.7, pip error

Tags: installation, pylint

I'm trying to install pylint with `pip install pylint`
But i've got this at the end of installation:

```
  Removing temporary dir c:\users\fixxxer\appdata\local\temp\pip_build_Fixxxer...
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\basecommand.py", line 122, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\commands\install.py", line 278, in run
    requirement_set.prepare_files(finder, force_root_egg_info=self.bundle, bundle=self.bundle)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\req.py", line 1229, in prepare_files
    req_to_install.run_egg_info()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\req.py", line 292, in run_egg_info
    logger.notify('Running setup.py (path:%s) egg_info for package %s' % (self.setup_py, self.name))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\req.py", line 265, in setup_py
    import setuptools
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 12, in <module>
    from setuptools.extension import Extension
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\setuptools\extension.py", line 7, in <module>
    from setuptools.dist import _get_unpatched
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 16, in <module>
    from setuptools.depends import Require
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\setuptools\depends.py", line 6, in <module>
    from setuptools import compat
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\setuptools\compat.py", line 19, in <module>
    from SimpleHTTPServer import SimpleHTTPRequestHandler
  File "C:\Python27\lib\SimpleHTTPServer.py", line 27, in <module>
    class SimpleHTTPRequestHandler(BaseHTTPServer.BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\SimpleHTTPServer.py", line 204, in SimpleHTTPRequestHandler
    mimetypes.init() # try to read system mime.types
  File "C:\Python27\lib\mimetypes.py", line 355, in init
    db.read_windows_registry()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\mimetypes.py", line 259, in read_windows_registry
    for ctype in enum_types(mimedb):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\mimetypes.py", line 249, in enum_types
    ctype = ctype.encode(default_encoding) # omit in 3.x!
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe0 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Any ideas how can i fix this or some workarounds?
How can i install it manually?

UPDATE.

replacing

`default_encoding = sys.getdefaultencoding()`

with

```
if sys.getdefaultencoding() != 'gbk':  
    reload(sys)  
    sys.setdefaultencoding('gbk')  
default_encoding = sys.getdefaultencoding()
```

does this:

```
Cleaning up...
  Removing temporary dir c:\users\fixxxer\appdata\local\temp\pip_build_Fixxxer...
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\basecommand.py", line 122, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\commands\install.py", line 278, in run
    requirement_set.prepare_files(finder, force_root_egg_info=self.bundle, bundle=self.bundle)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\req.py", line 1229, in prepare_files
    req_to_install.run_egg_info()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\req.py", line 292, in run_egg_info
    logger.notify('Running setup.py (path:%s) egg_info for package %s' % (self.setup_py, self.name))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\req.py", line 265, in setup_py
    import setuptools
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 12, in <module>
    from setuptools.extension import Extension
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\setuptools\extension.py", line 7, in <module>
    from setuptools.dist import _get_unpatched
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 16, in <module>
    from setuptools.depends import Require
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\setuptools\depends.py", line 6, in <module>
    from setuptools import compat
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\setuptools\compat.py", line 19, in <module>
    from SimpleHTTPServer import SimpleHTTPRequestHandler
  File "C:\Python27\lib\SimpleHTTPServer.py", line 27, in <module>
    class SimpleHTTPRequestHandler(BaseHTTPServer.BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\SimpleHTTPServer.py", line 204, in SimpleHTTPRequestHandler
    mimetypes.init() # try to read system mime.types
  File "C:\Python27\lib\mimetypes.py", line 359, in init
    db.read_windows_registry()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\mimetypes.py", line 263, in read_windows_registry
    for ctype in enum_types(mimedb):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\mimetypes.py", line 249, in enum_types
    ctype = ctype.encode(default_encoding) # omit in 3.x!
UnicodeDecodeError: 'gbk' codec can't decode bytes in position 4-5: illegal multibyte sequence
```

Answer (score 1):

Found a problem.

There was a few MIME types with Cyrillic names in

`HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\MIME\Database\Content Type`

Removed them and problem was solved.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error and this helped me https://stackoverflow.com/a/23278373/2571607

Basically, open C:\Python27\Lib\mimetypes.py

replace

```
‘default_encoding = sys.getdefaultencoding()’
```

with

```
if sys.getdefaultencoding() != 'gbk':  
    reload(sys)  
    sys.setdefaultencoding('gbk')  
default_encoding = sys.getdefaultencoding()
```